# How to read dynamic file naming for csv file in ssis?

Tags: ssis

Hi how do i read file with dynamic filename? In ssis for importing csv data to my database.

The csv file naming convention can be like: File-ddmmyyyyhhmmss.txt

can anyone advise?

Comment: Is it helpful ? http://www.sqlis.com/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Steps for dynamically load the flat file into the destination.

- Use the `Foreach loop container`
- In Collection tab, Select Enumerator as `Foreach File Enumerator` and
  Configure as follows.

Folder: Location of your source files

Files : `File-*.txt` [Since your file naming is something like File-ddmmyyyyhhmmss.txt]

Retrive File Name : Select `Fully qualified Name` [which brings entire location of your file]

[image]

- In `Variable Mapping`, Create a variable to store the `Full file path`
  and configure as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

- Create a `Flat file connection` using sample file.
- Select a Flat file and go to `properties`. Find the `expression property`
  and `map the variable to the connection string` as shown in the
  following screenshot.
  [image]

> Important Note:

If you want to validate the file name and existence of the file name before loading into the destination table. Use the script component inside the `For each loop container` and validate.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a step by step guide

1. Use the `Foreach Loop Container` (File Enumerator type) , set your Files mask as `File-??????????????.txt`
2. Map a string variable to capture the match files.
3. Add a `Script Task` inside this container to parse the string variable to match the actual file naming convention (hint: use regex). Any successful matches will act like a filter larger list of files found by the `Foreach Loop Container`.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this learning series from Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-2-adding-looping-with-ssis?view=sql-server-2017